# How to add a space between digits and unit of measure in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a dataset where sometimes the unit of measure is not separated from the number by a space, and I would like to add it in. I have a list of units of measure that may be used in the dataset and I want to make sure that every time they appear there is a space.
My data is something like:
 `mydata <- c("black box 125CM", "10KG white chair", "bottle of water 1000ML")`
And I would like:
 `result <- c("black box 125 CM", "10 KG white chair", "bottle of water 1000 ML")`
The units of measure that might appear:
 `measure <- c("ML", "MG", "F", "CM", "CPR", "FL", "CPS", "KG")`

So far I have tried (but it is not working):

```
  for (i in 1:NROW(measure)) {
    replacement <- paste0("\\s", measure[i])
    result <- gsub("(?<=[[:digit:]])"measure[i], replacement, mydata, perl = TRUE)
    }
```

If it were for one substitution I would be able to do it with:

```
result <- gsub("(?<=[[:digit:]])MG", " MG", mydata, perl = TRUE)
```

I just do not know how I am supposed to write `measure[i]` in the gsub function, I cannot find the right syntax.
Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try something like: `gsub(paste0( "(?<=[[:digit:]])(", paste(measure, collapse="|"), ")"), " \\1", mydata, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can do this.

```r
gsub(paste0("(?<=[0-9])(", paste(measure, collapse = "|"), ")"), " \\1",
     mydata, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "black box 125 CM"        "10 KG white chair"       "bottle of water 1000 ML"
```

Comment: It does exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata <- c("black box 125CM", "10KG white chair", "bottle of water 1000ML")
stringr::str_replace_all(mydata, "[:digit:]([ML|MG|F|C[M|PR|PS]|FL|KG])", " \\1")
```

Gives

```
[1] "black box 12 CM"        "1 KG white chair"       "bottle of water 100 ML"
```

Note the special handling of the three cases which all begin with `C`.

As an aside, if I were having to be this fussy about spaces, I'd also be minded to be fussy about getting the case of the SI units corrrect: "KG" is not kilogramme but Kelvin  ⋅ 6.674×10<sup>−11</sup> m<sup>3</sup>⋅kg<sup>−1</sup>⋅s<sup>−2</sup>, as near as I can figure it!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and works for me.

```
mydata <- c("black box 125CM", "10KG white chair", "bottle of water 1000ML")

measure <- c("ML", "MG", "F", "CM", "CPR", "FL", "CPS", "KG")
measure <- paste(measure, collapse = "|")

result <- sub(paste0("([", measure, "])"), " \\1", mydata)
```

edit: This will also add spaces if there is already a space,r2evans solution would be more preferable.

Comment: This will add the space even if it exists already, won't it?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I will edit the answer to make that clear. In that case your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

If, as in the example, the measure always appears after the numbers, then this works:

```
sub("(\\d+)", "\\1 ", mydata)
[1] "black box 125 CM"        "10 KG white chair"       "bottle of water 1000 ML"
```